# Collect data from a MYSQL server that requries VPN access and insert it into another SQL server

Tags: mysql, server, vpn

I need to be able to pull data from a MYSQL server that requires a VPN connection and insert it into a regular SQL server that doesn't not require a VPN to accesss. The purpose of this is I have an app that is developed on a low-code platform that doesn't support VPN access. The overall connection should look like this:

My app ---> Solution/3rd party app(the part im asking about) ---> VPN ---> MYSQL server

I am not too knowledgeable about automatically connecting to SQL servers especially ones that require VPN connections, so any advice or pointing into the right direction helps. Thanks!

Comment: What's your question about this? What keeps you from starting that VPN connection before copying the data?

Comment: The process is supposed to be automated and be able to be done by itself everyday at midnight.

Comment: Linux? make a ceron job and write a shell script that  does everything by it self